# How to update a particular repetative div (with different data each time) on a page without reloading entire page?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, wordpress, xhtml

I am using wordpress and have set up latest posts archive as front page.

I am using a plugin to show post publish time in the format "time ago".

I wish to update this time ago stamp automatically for each listed post respectively on the front page archive.

this is architecture of the page -

```
<div id="posts">
<article class="post-1">
<div id="post-title">
TITLE
</div>
<div id="publish-date-time">
<div class="post-meta-data">
<div class="post-date-time">
30 seconds ago
</div>
</div>
</div>
</article>
<article class="post-2">
<div id="post-title">
TITLE
</div>
<div id="publish-date-time">
<div class="post-meta-data">
<div class="post-date-time">
30 seconds ago
</div>
</div>
</div>
</article>
</div>
```

Now I want to update div with time ago stamp for each article without reloading page.

I have tried -

```
$(article).each( funtion() {
setinterval( function() {
$(this).find("#publish-date-time").load(location.href + " #publish-date-time");
}, 60000);
return false;
```

but this adds various time stamps on only the first article on front page and does nothing else.

With my limited knowledge of ajax, wordpress, jquery and web development I can only guess that I need Ajax to get post date for each post and then feed it to each post-publish-time through html or text, but I dont know how to do it.

Help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.